# Choosing an API for AD-based authorization in a Windows app

Tags: .net, active-directory, authorization

We are building a rich-client app (WPF) that uses the logged-on user information for auditing and authorization.

I'm trying to decide between three different APIs for accessing this information:

- `System.Management` classes (WMI queries)
- `System.Security.Principal` classes (WindowsIdentity, etc)
- `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` classes (UserPrincipal, etc)

The use cases are:

- Get the current username
- Get all the users in group X
- Get all the groups the current user belongs to
- Is the current user in group X?
- Is user X in group Y?

I have some proofs of concept for each method, but I'd like some objective reasons to use one or other. I'd appreciate facts on the following aspects:

- Testability
- Performance
- Ease of use
- Ease of deployment

  - In test/production
  - In developer's computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WMI** 
is nice regarding testability because there are many (native/.NET/script...) out there whcih can be used for the same tasks, result comparison etc.
What in my experience can be rather difficult is deployment/setup regarding security/communication etc.

**System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement**
In my exeperience very easy to use and deploy... for developer's computer you can (sacrificing some subtler aspects) use the same code and test it with the local User/Groups if need be. Regarding Performance this is usually more than sufficient but can be tweaked a bit depending of you needs (ad-hoc AD queries versus permanent conn etc.).
Should there ever be the need to not only query but create/change Users/Groups etc. this is an easy thing to do...

I didn't use *System.Security.Principal* alot so can't say much about it... the more current part of .NET is *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement* and works really well :-)

Comment: +1 I'd second the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement recommendation - if you haven't already, definitely read [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) for a great intro